# how can i do it: library's callback wait until user choose from popover and then get return

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with understanding how work with view/delegate and completion.

I use library which have callback - something like: 
func youShouldChoose()->String.

I desided to give a choice to user and open popover. But I don't understand how to return the selected value.

I read about completion. So i've tried this:

```
func youShouldChoose() -> String {        
       askUser() 

       return self.valueForResult    //This line is executed earlier than askUser is finished
    }


func  askUser(){
          showAlert(completion: {(result)->Void in
           self.valueForResult = result
    })
}


func showAlert(completion:@escaping (_ result:String)->Void)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(...)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
              completion(textField.text)
        }))
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter text:"
     })

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil )
     }
```

How can I wait until askUser() will end completely? Is there a way to return value from completion to my library?

Comment: Your first function is not returning a closure, it just calls a function and then (synchronously) returns a String. Your second function, `askUser()`, is already doing something like what you describe, since `valueForResult` is assigned after the user performs the action on the alert. Finally, the third function is exactly what you describe (returns a closure & executes it asynchronously). I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: *Is there a way to return value*? No, there isn't,  you need *something like* `func youShouldChoose(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void)`

Comment: @Alladinian, could you tell me, how can i take result from the third function and return to the first?  Because i should return result to library's function only after user is choosed something

Comment: Use the protocol to get a call when the user selects something.

Comment: @ElTomato,  could you show an example? Because i don't understand how i can return from another method to my start point - youShouldChoose()

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to solve out this problem:
1. Use loop. Showing view until flag is false

```
askUser() //we should set flag to true here  
while( flag == false ) {
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode, 1, true);
}
return self.valueForResult
```

2. Use semaphore

   ```
   let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
   askUser()   
   semaphore.lock()
   return self.valueForResult
   ```

Comment: Don't do it this way (even if it works). Instead use this `func youShouldChoose(_ completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) { completion("foo") }`. Try to understand how a completion block works. That will make you a better programmer. I'm not sure what `CFRunLoopRunInMode ` does, but it is generally a very bad idea to check in a loop whether the state of a value changed. And as far as I know `DispatchSemaphore` blocks the current thread. If your are doing this on the main thread, then the user is not able to interact with your app any more until `.signal()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **example** solution (Swift 4.2 / 5.0):

```
func youShouldChoose(_ completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
    askUser(completion) // handing over the completion block to `askUser.

    // Alternative completion block execution:
    // askUser { (enteredText) in
    //     // This block is called when the "Click" action button on the alert was tapped.
    //     completion(enteredText)
    // }
}

func askUser(_ completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
    showAlert(completion) // handing over the completion block to `showAlert`.
}

func showAlert(_ completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Click", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        if let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let text = textField.text {
            completion(text) // -> handing over the text of the textField!
        } else {
            // No text field or text available. Something went wrong!
        }
    }))
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter text:"
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// How to use `youShouldChoose `: 
func foo() {
    youShouldChoose { (enteredText) in
        // This block is called when `youShouldChoose` is finished.
        print(enteredText) // -> prints the user's entered text.
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your example, but as i understand it doesn't solve my problem. youShouldChoose(completion: ...)   print("hello") .   I have to have "Hello" only after completion is finished. But in that case hello would be earlier. Please correct me if i am wrong. I need to wait in main thread while user choose something in window. This example don't solve it

Comment: @artyom I made an edit to my example. Look at the `foo` function below. "Hello" is printed, when the completion block is finished.